# Как соотнести экземпляр класса с коллекцией, его содержащей?

Tags: java

У меня есть различные объекты, которые я храню в различных коллекциях.

Как реализовать метод, который по экземпляру класса добавлял бы этот экземпляр именно в ту коллекцию, что содержит эти объекты? Допустим все эти классы Car, Plane, Train наследуются от общего родителя Transport.

Есть ли смысл создать карту, которая бы ставила в соответствие классу коллекцию, содержащую экземпляры этого класса?

```
Collection<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();
Collection<Plane> planes = new HashSet<>();
Collection<Train> trains = new HashSet<>();

Map<Transport,Collection<Transport>> bondMap;

public void add(Transport transport) {
// тут по классу аргумента добавление в соответствующую коллекцию
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что хорошего простого решения тут нет, но можно что-то поизобретать.

Вдохновлялся [Typesafe Heterogeneous Container](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA142&ots=yZGnPnt0TX&hl=ru&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q&f=false) из Joshua Bloch - Effective Java:

```
class TypeCollections<T> {
    private Map<Class<? extends T>, Collection<? extends T>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <E extends T> void putCollection( Class<E> clazz, Collection<E> collection ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( clazz, "argument 'clazz' must be non-null" );
        Objects.requireNonNull( collection, "argument 'collection' must be non-null" );
        map.put( clazz, collection );
    }

    public <E extends T> void addValue( E value ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( value, "Null value not accepted" );

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // здесь игнорируются предупреждения компилятора о небезопасном
        //   приведении типа, но т.к. мы знаем, что для
        //   типа E у нас лежит или Collection<E> или ничего, 
        //   то просим компилятор заткнуться.
        Collection<E> collection = (Collection<E>)map.get( value.getClass() );
        if ( collection != null ) {
            collection.add( value );
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
class Transport{};

class Car extends Transport {};
class Plane extends Transport {};
class Train extends Transport {};

class Spaceship extends Transport {};

public class TypeSafety {
    HashSet<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Plane> planes = new HashSet<>();
    Collection<Train> trains = new HashSet<>();

    // будет принимать только классы, наследующие Transport
    TypeCollections<Transport> tsc = new TypeCollections<Transport>();
    {   
        tsc.putCollection( Car.class, cars );
        // поскольку Set<Plane> наследует Collection<Plane>, можно
        //   добавить один из подклассов Collection, если совпадает тип параметра
        tsc.putCollection( Plane.class, planes );
        tsc.putCollection( Train.class, trains );
    }

    public void add( Transport transport ) {
        tsc.addValue( transport );
    }

    public void printCollections() {
        System.out.println( cars.toString() );
        System.out.println( planes.toString() );
        System.out.println( trains.toString() );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        TypeSafety test = new TypeSafety();

        List<Transport> transports = Arrays.asList( 
                new Train(),
                new Car(),
                new Plane(), new Plane(),
                new Train(),
                new Plane(),
                new Car(), new Car(),
                new Spaceship()
            );

        for( Transport t : transports ) {
            test.add( t );
        }

        test.printCollections();
        // Вывод:
        //   [sandbox.Car@7852e922, sandbox.Car@3d4eac69, sandbox.Car@55f96302]
        //   [sandbox.Plane@33909752, sandbox.Plane@70dea4e, sandbox.Plane@4e25154f]
        //   [sandbox.Train@5c647e05, sandbox.Train@6d06d69c]
        //
        // Spaceship мимо пролетел. 
    }
}
```

У этого решения полно недостатков:

- Нельзя использовать для обобщенных классов. Например:

  ```
  TypeCollections<Comparable<String>> t = new TypeCollections<>();
  {
      t.putCollection( Comparable<String>.class, new ArrayList<Comparable<String>>());
  }
  ```

  не скомпилируется, т.к. использовать `Comparable<String>.class` нельзя, поскольку во время выполнения информация о параметре типа стирается, и ссылки на разные версии `Comparable` свелись бы к одной. У Bloch упоминается техника [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.ru/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) (по ссылке в комментариях есть пример реализации для коллекций).
- Игнорируются наследники. Например, если добавить класс `class SportCar extends Car {};` то код:

  ```
  test.add( new SportCar() );
  ```

не добавит этот объект в коллекцию `cars` из примера выше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться оператором `instanceof`, проверяющим является ли то, что слева экземпляром класса справа:

```
public void add(Transport transport) 
{
    if(transport instanceof Car)
    {
        cars.add(transport );
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда мне придется прописать три оператора if, а если я добавлю еще объектов и коллекций, то еще дописывать if'ы. Возможно ли с помощью вспомогательной карты это оптимальней сделать?

Comment: @will_hunting, ну... Можно, наверное, попробовать циклом пробежаться по ключам карты и проверить их класс на совпадение с переданным экземпляром...